# Calculate Average in Database SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I need to get the Average, rounded to 2 decimal points, of a difference of two dates.

Using Entity Framework Core I used the following:

```
var average = await games
  .Where(x => x.Finish.HasValue)
  .AverageAsync(x => Math.Round((x.Finish.Value - x.Start).TotalDays, 2));
```

This seems to be running in memory.

How can I calculate the average on the database (SQL)?

Comment: What is the target database type (because currently there is no universal way of doing timespan calculations server side)?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: `AverageAsync` itself should be calculated on the database. Your expression is being evaluated in memory probably because of `TimeSpan` operations like `TotalDays`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the `Average`, but the time span calculation - currently EF Core (2.x) does not support generic SQL translation of time span calculations.

For SqlServer though you could use some of the [DateDiff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffday?view=efcore-2.1) methods introduced in EF Core 2.1. All they return `int` values, so you can't use directly `DateDiffDay` to get the equivalent of `TimeSpan.TotalDays`, but you could use `DateDiffHour / 24d` or `DateDiffMinute / (24d * 60)` etc. to simulate it.

For instance,

```
var average = await games
    .Where(x => x.Finish.HasValue)
    .AverageAsync(x => Math.Round(EF.Functions.DateDiffHour(x.Start, x.Finish.Value) / 24d, 2));
```

translates to

```sql
  SELECT AVG(ROUND(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [x].[Start], [x].[Finish]) / 24.0E0, 2))
  FROM [Game] AS [x]
  WHERE [x].[Finish] IS NOT NULL
```